# Oven caught fire while using self-clean

Tags: oven, fire

Oven caught fire while using self-clean.  Now the oven looks bad (greyish tinge) - how do I clean it?  (I'm only renting!!)

Answer (score 3):

Grease fires do happen with self cleaning ovens, it's why I stopped using that feature: I didn't feel like I could leave it to get on with the cycle safely and I couldn't sit there for hours.

Cleaning it afterwards isn't a big deal, the grey dust is ash and you can vacuum a lot of it out once the oven is clean. If any ash remains good old soapy water will get off the rest.